# Captcha Issue when using Selenium TOR socks proxy

Tags: python, selenium, tor

Newb issue probably. I am trying to have Selenium use the Firefox browser with the IP from TOR, below my script

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; `Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36")`

profile.update_preferences() 
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')
```

The issue I am having is that once launched, the page automatically launches the captcha -
"One more step
Please complete the security check to access whatismyipaddress.com". Can anyone at least point me into the right direction as to what is your best guess for the cause?

Thank you!

Comment: Cloudflare recognizes Tor and the fact that your session is new and they can't identify you, so they serve the captcha page.  Not much you can do about it but solve it and move on.

Comment: Here is an article describing Cloudflare related issues while using Tor browser https://blog.torproject.org/trouble-cloudflare.